# finding the exact value of $\sin 195^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to find the exact value of sine of $195^\circ$.

I know the traditional table of some special values of trigonometric functions:[image]

I am also familiar with fundamental identities:
[image]
and with the addition and subtraction formulas:
[image]
But I don't know how I should properly break up $195^\circ$ (so that I could apply any of those formulas) as $195^\circ$ cannot be split into an integer number of constituencies, one or some of which would be equal to $30^\circ$ or $45^\circ$ or $60^\circ$ or $90^\circ$.
What should I do?

Comment: Hint: $195=180+15,$ and [$\sin(15^\circ)=\frac{ \sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2} }4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_trigonometric_values).

Comment: 195 = 150 + 45. What can you say about 150 and 30?

Comment: @AnneBauval - But how do I go about 15?

Comment: @Student - You mean that 150 is five times bigger than 30, right?

Comment: Or: $195=180+15$ and $15=60-45.$

Comment: Not really what I was hinting at. Do you know about related angles? 150 and 30 are supplementary angles. What can you say about the relation between their sine and cosine?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/468350

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$\sin(195^\circ)=\sin(60^\circ+135^\circ)=\sin(60^\circ)\cos(135^\circ)+\cos(60^\circ)\sin(135^\circ).$$

Further, since $135^\circ=180^\circ-45^\circ$, we have
$$\sin(135^\circ)=\sin(45^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},\quad\cos(135^\circ)=-\cos(45^\circ)=-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}.$$

Conclude from here.